# How to get updated page number from antd table if the last record of table gets deleted?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd table in my application. I have also used pagination with it. Further I have custom settings of displaying 10 records per page and the records I am getting from the database are 11, now being on second page if I delete the last record which will be the only record on second page, I do get back only 10 records but my page still remains 2 instead going back to 1. How do I cater this? Any help will be appreciated.

```
            <Table
              columns={columns}
              dataSource={data}
              pagination={{
                defaultPageSize: 10,
                position: ["none", "bottomCenter"],
                total: count,
                showSizeChanger: true,
                current: page, 
                onChange: (page, pageSize) => onTabChange(page, pageSize), //this only fires if I 
                                                                            click on any page number
              }}
            />
```

Edit: I have created a small demo to show the problem I am facing here on sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-settings-antd4151-forked-ilz3l?file=/index.js
Here if you delete the last item from page 3 while keeping the console open, you will see the page still remains 3 instead of changing to 2, how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this? In my case the table is updating to the previous page but the onChange function is not being called which means I never go and fetch more data.

Answer (score 0):

Just sync page number to react state after response is ok.

You can calculate current page number by **total count** (back-end should provide) and **current page size** (front-end known or back-end provided) like this:

```
this.setState({
  page: Math.ceil(total / pageSize),
});
```